# How upload XAP file with Windows Phone Power Tools on tablet?

Tags: windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine, windows-store-apps

I would need to upload a XAP file done for Windows 8 Phone to a Windows 8.1 Tablet. 
I know that Windows Phone Power Tools do it but since this tool was done for Windows 8 Phone and not for Tablet, for it. Could I upload this XAP into my Tablet with it? Is it possible?
Thanks in advance 
Best Regards 
Alejandro

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8 apps are not compatible or in other words do not work in Windows 8. Though you can share some code using PCL (Portable Class Libraries), the development environment and architecture is different for both.

So the answer for your question is, it is not possible to deploy or run your Windows Phone apps on a Windows 8 tablet.